# Using UTF-16 encoding in python

Tags: python, utf-16

I'm trying to encode non-ascii characters in python using utf-16-le, and here's the snippet of the code for this:

```
import os
import sys

def run():
    print sys.getdefaultencoding()
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-16-le')
    print sys.getdefaultencoding()
    test_dir = unit_test_utils.get_test_dir("utkarsh")
    dir_name_1 = '東京'
    ....
    ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

When this code is run, this is the error seen:

```
# /u/bin/python-qs /root/python/tests/abc.py -c  /root/test.conf 
  File "/root/python/tests/abc.py", line 27
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe6' in file /root/python/tests/abc.py on line 27, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

How can this be fixed? I tried adding this line to the beginning of the file, but to no avail:

```
# -*- coding: utf-16-le -*-
```

The error this time around was:

```
# /u/bin/python-qs /root/python/tests/abc.py -c  /root/test.conf
  File "/root/python/tests/abc.py", line 2
    import os
import sys
...
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Edit:

Line 27: dir_name_1 = '東京'

Comment: Can you include a complete example that produces this error?

Comment: Is your source code written in utf-16 encoding ? Check with `file abc.py`.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Output: UTF-8 Unicode Java program text

Comment: Do ***not*** use `sys.setdefaultencoding()`. You are trying to auto-set broken bones there rather than not break your bones in the first place. Read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html instead and handle Unicode properly.

Comment: Note that Python source code encoding can't handle anything but single-byte and UTF-8 codecs. UTF-16 and UTF-32 are **not** supported.

Comment: If you are handling *data*, there is no need to declare a source code encoding. That is only needed if you need to specify non-ASCII string literals in your code, but you could just use `\xhh` or `\uhhhh` escape sequences in those literals instead. A source code encoding declaration won't help with encoding and decoding data in your program.

Comment: It says error in line27...you didn't show line 27 on your post?

Comment: What is the version of your Python interpreter? The `print` syntax suggests it should be 2.x, but I cannot understand why a Python 2.x would choke on a (byte) string initialization.

Comment: @SergeBallesta `# python -V
Python 2.4.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is (almost) fine in the code you show. You have a source file encoded in utf-8 (as stated by your comment on the result of the `file` command), so the line

```
dir_name_1 = '東京'
```

is in fact (as you are using a Python 2.x):

```
dir_name_1 = '\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe4\xba\xac' # utf8 for 東京
```

The only problem is that on line 27 (that you failed to show) you are doing something with that utf8 encoded string, probably trying to convert it (explicitely or implicitely) to unicode *without specifying any encoding*, so ascii is taken as default and error is then normal since `\xe6` in not in ascii range. You should explicitely decode the string with `dir_name_1.decode('utf8')`

Comment: Line 27: `dir_name_1 = '東京'`. I've updated the post with this.

Comment: How do I get the characters UTF-16 encoded, if it is possible? One of the comments says that UTF-16 and UTF-32 are not supported for source editor.

Comment: Can I add them to the file and read them specifying that the contents are UTF-16 encoded?

Comment: @Maddy If the file is UTF8-encoded, you can get utf16-le encoded bytes that way: `dir_name_1 = '東京'; utf16_dirname_1 = dir_name_1.decode('utf8').encode(utf16-le)`

Comment: I tried your suggestion as: `#!/usr/bin/python; import os; import sys; dir_name_1 = '東京'; utf16_dirname_1 = dir_name_1.decode('utf8').encode(utf16-le)`. But it fails saying:              `$ python test1.py
  File "test1.py", line 6
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe6' in file test1.py on line 6, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`. I tried a few suggestions from the website mentioned, but the result was the same.

Comment: @Maddy: I forgot to tell you to declare the utf8 encoding. The python file must start with `# -*- coding: utf8-*-` or if first line declares a shell (such as `#! /usr/bin/env python`, the coding line must be the second one.

Comment: That worked, thanks! It complains that utf16-le is an unrecognized encoding format, but I'll look that up.

Comment: idle literally doesn't even allow us to save the file if there's special chars in it tho. And the comment header doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Pete: My IDLE has no problem with Latin1 file, and in utf8 mode, accept all unicode characters up to 0xFFFF (but not above...). That being said, this is now a rather old post. If you have a problem now, and if the current answer does not solve it, you should ask a new question, showing your research and explaining how the existing SO answers cannot help. But please be specific: *does not work* is far from enough...

Comment: sorry about vagueness. update: it fixed when I reinstalled